# Ajax autocomplete no funciona al publicar en servidor

Tags: php, ajax, cpanel, autocomplete

Mi problema es el siguiente, hice un input que se autocompleta, utilizando ajax, php y mysql. En mi servidor local (XAMPP) funciona perfectamente, pero al momento de subirlo a un servidor privado para publicar mi sitio, dejo de funcionar el autocomplete.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```js
//INICIO AUTOCOMPLETE PAIS DE PROCEDENCIA
$(function() {
    $( "#paisProcedencia" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: 'php/ajax-autocomplete-paises.php',
    focus: function(event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#paisProcedencia").val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#paisProcedencia").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#paisProcedenciaId").val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }  
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<div>" + item.label + "</div>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
});
//FIN AUTOCOMPLETE PAIS DE PROCEDENCIA
```

```html
<label class="form-label">País de Procedencia<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="paisProcedencia" name="paisProcedencia"  placeholder="Buscar País" />
```

Y el codigo de PHP es:

```
<?php

include 'conexion_be.php';

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET['term']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM paises WHERE descripcion LIKE '$term%'";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$result = [];

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $result[] = array(
        'value' => $data['id'],
        'label' => $data['descripcion']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
flush();
?>
```

No creo que el problema sea el funcionamiento del código, porque como dije en XAMPP funciona correctamente.
Lo que probé fue cambiar la ruta del source en el código ajax y poner la ruta absoluta pero nada..
Pienso que quizás es un problema de permisos, pero la verdad no se.

De hecho figura ok el status de la request:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A alguien le paso alguna vez? Se agradece cualquier ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: En la ventana donde se muestra información de la petición, haz clic en "Response" y dinos qué aparece, tal vez sea un mensaje de error y te de la pista para encontrar la solución.

Comment: Hola, como estas? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Justo justo estaba mirando eso, y no me daba cuenta de algo.... me habia quedado un "echo" del archivo conexion.php que estuve probando cuando subi los archivos, y se ve que ese echo me impedia capturar correctamente el JSON. Muchas gracias